# How to install an .exe file?

Tags: window

I am trying to run a Window software (.exe) but I couldn't figure it out. Please someone help me I would greatly appreciate your help.

I am trying to run this Window software on Ubuntu 16.04.

Link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5c02l5hl3b95vl/FaucetCollectorSetup.exe?dl=0

Thank you!

Comment: I was able to install wine but when I opened the file with Wine it says I needed to install Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6 or Higher. I did that but it didn't go through. Any ideas thanks!

Comment: [WineHQ - .NET Framework 4.6](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32828)

Answer (score 0):

Try out Wine.
Search it in the Software Center. (It may get buggy with some `.exe` files, so there's a probability that it'll crash)